# AsyncApexJob.CronTriggerId present but no actual CronTrigger record

Tags: scheduled-apex, asyncapexjob

*Maybe it has always been this way but ...*

If you execute `System.abortJob(id)`, the `AsyncApexJob.CronTriggerId` still retains a value but there's no `CronTrigger` parent record

Given the following code ...

```
public inherited sharing class FooSchedulable implements System.Schedulable{

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        String[] logEntries = new List<String> ();

        logEntries.add('Jobs before we abort ourselves:');
        AsyncApexJob job = getJob();
        logEntries.add(getJobDetails(job)); // <== what does AsyncApexJob look like before abort

        System.abortJob(sc.getTriggerId());  // abort ourselves

        logEntries.add('\n\nJobs after we abort ourselves:');
        job = getJob();
        logEntries.add(getJobDetails(job));  // <== what does AsyncApexJob look like after abort

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,String.join(logEntries,'\n'));
        return;
    }

    String getJobDetails(AsyncApexJob job) {
        return job.ApexClass.Name + ' ' + job.CreatedDate + ' ' + job.CronTriggerId + ' ' +
            job.JobType + ' ' +job.CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name;
    }

    public AsyncApexJob getJob() {
        return [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, ApexClass.Name, JobType, CronTriggerId,
            CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name,
            CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.JobType
        FROM AsyncApexJob
        WHERE ApexClass.Name = 'FooSchedulable' AND
        JobType = 'ScheduledApex'
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1][0];
    }
```

The debug log shows:

```
Jobs before we abort ourselves:
FooSchedulable 2022-10-28 22:23:11 08e0300000OQYo3AAH ScheduledApex FooSchedulableJobName

Jobs after we abort ourselves:
FooSchedulable 2022-10-28 22:23:11 08e0300000OQYo3AAH ScheduledApex null <== No CronTrigger.CronJobDetail !!
```

If I query directly for the `CronJobTrigger`

```
SELECT Id, State FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = '08e0300000OQYo3AAH'
```

Result: `No rows found`.  *Note there is no `IsDeleted` field on `CronTrigger`*

### Conclusion

Looks like a referential integrity issue to me. A lookup field pointing at a non-existent record.  What am I missing?